# change of edited cell color and save style with Ag Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I need to provide a background color for edited cell
I found this method, but it changes the column color of the edited cell.

```
const cell = params.api.getFocusedCell();
if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
cell.column.colDef.cellStyle = {fontWeight: '550',background: 'coral'};
params.api.redrawRows()
}
params.api.refreshCells(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
cell.column.colDef.cellStyle = {fontWeight: '550',background: 'coral'};
```

for

```
cell.style.background = 'coral';
cell.style.fontWeight = '550';
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. but it does not work